# FileHelpers3 - recursive object

Tags: c#, filehelpers, delimited

This object fills just fine

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class LvMenuItems
{
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ControlPanelSequence { get; set; }
}

[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class LvMenuItems
{
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ControlPanelSequence { get; set; }

    [LVMenuItems]
    public LVMenutItems menu items {get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible to embed a copy of the same structure as an attribute of an object to introduce recurrsion?

Comment: I should clarify that the second declaration errors out on the last line where we try to resuse the same object as an attribute within itself to enable recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I was going about this completely wrong. The correct way it to declare a single object that corresponds to the delimited file and then use that object to fill a second object that handles recursion.